# I need help with changing the owner of a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

I'm trying to assist a client in changing the owner of a contract, but the situation is as follows: He has two contracts, A and B. Contract A is the owner of contract B. He only has access to the owner wallet of contract A, but within contract A, there is no function calling the `transferOwnership` function inherited from `Ownable` in contract B. I would like some guidance on how to make this owner change in contract B. I've tried various approaches without success. I attempted to create an intermediary contract for this purpose, but it didn't work. I would appreciate any help. There is a substantial amount of BNB locked in contract B, and my client wants this amount back to pay me and continue his business. I'm willing to share half of this amount with anyone who can help me.

Below the code contract A

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "./DividendPayingToken.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";
import "./IterableMapping.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";
import "./IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "./IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "./IUniswapV2Router.sol";

contract RewardHunters is ERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapV2Router;
    address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;

    address public immutable bounceFixedSaleWallet;

    bool private swapping;

    RHTDividendTracker public dividendTracker;

    address public liquidityWallet;

    uint256 public maxSellTransactionAmount = 1000000 * (10**18);
    uint256 public swapTokensAtAmount = 200000 * (10**18);

    uint256 public immutable BNBRewardsFee;
    uint256 public immutable liquidityFee;
    uint256 public immutable totalFees;

    // sells have fees of 12 and 6 (10 * 1.2 and 5 * 1.2)
    uint256 public immutable sellFeeIncreaseFactor = 120; 

    // use by default 300,000 gas to process auto-claiming dividends
    uint256 public gasForProcessing = 300000;


    /*   Fixed Sale   */

    // timestamp for when purchases on the fixed-sale are available to early participants
    uint256 public immutable fixedSaleStartTimestamp = 1627393800; //July 26, 13:50 UTC, 2021

    // the fixed-sale will be open to the public 10 minutes after fixedSaleStartTimestamp,
    // or after 600 buys, whichever comes first.
    uint256 public immutable fixedSaleEarlyParticipantDuration = 600;
    uint256 public immutable fixedSaleEarlyParticipantBuysThreshold = 600;

    // track number of buys. once this reaches fixedSaleEarlyParticipantBuysThreshold,
    // the fixed-sale will be open to the public even if it's still in the first 10 minutes
    uint256 public numberOfFixedSaleBuys;
    // track who has bought
    mapping (address => bool) public fixedSaleBuyers;

    /******************/



    // timestamp for when the token can be traded freely on PanackeSwap
    uint256 public immutable tradingEnabledTimestamp = 1627394400; //JuLy 27, 14:00 UTC, 2021

    // exlcude from fees and max transaction amount
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFees;

    // addresses that can make transfers before presale is over
    mapping (address => bool) private canTransferBeforeTradingIsEnabled;

    mapping (address => bool) public fixedSaleEarlyParticipants;

    // store addresses that a automatic market maker pairs. Any transfer *to* these addresses
    // could be subject to a maximum transfer amount
    mapping (address => bool) public automatedMarketMakerPairs;

    event UpdateDividendTracker(address indexed newAddress, address indexed oldAddress);

    event UpdateUniswapV2Router(address indexed newAddress, address indexed oldAddress);

    event ExcludeFromFees(address indexed account, bool isExcluded);
    event ExcludeMultipleAccountsFromFees(address[] accounts, bool isExcluded);

    event FixedSaleEarlyParticipantsAdded(address[] participants);

    event SetAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address indexed pair, bool indexed value);

    event LiquidityWalletUpdated(address indexed newLiquidityWallet, address indexed oldLiquidityWallet);

    event GasForProcessingUpdated(uint256 indexed newValue, uint256 indexed oldValue);

    event FixedSaleBuy(address indexed account, uint256 indexed amount, bool indexed earlyParticipant, uint256 numberOfBuyers);

    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
    );

    event SendDividends(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 amount
    );

    event ProcessedDividendTracker(
        uint256 iterations,
        uint256 claims,
        uint256 lastProcessedIndex,
        bool indexed automatic,
        uint256 gas,
        address indexed processor
    );

    constructor() public ERC20("RHT", "RHT") {
        uint256 _BNBRewardsFee = 10;
        uint256 _liquidityFee = 5;

        BNBRewardsFee = _BNBRewardsFee;
        liquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
        totalFees = _BNBRewardsFee.add(_liquidityFee);


        dividendTracker = new RHTDividendTracker();

        liquidityWallet = owner();

        
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
         // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
        address _uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        uniswapV2Pair = _uniswapV2Pair;

        _setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(_uniswapV2Pair, true);

        address _bounceFixedSaleWallet = 0x4Fc4bFeDc5c82644514fACF716C7F888a0C73cCc;
        bounceFixedSaleWallet = _bounceFixedSaleWallet;

        // exclude from receiving dividends
        dividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(address(dividendTracker));
        dividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(address(this));
        dividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(owner());
        dividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(address(_uniswapV2Router));
        dividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(_bounceFixedSaleWallet);

        // exclude from paying fees or having max transaction amount
        excludeFromFees(liquidityWallet, true);
        excludeFromFees(address(this), true);

        // enable owner and fixed-sale wallet to send tokens before presales are over
        canTransferBeforeTradingIsEnabled[owner()] = true;
        canTransferBeforeTradingIsEnabled[_bounceFixedSaleWallet] = true;

        /*
            _mint is an internal function in ERC20.sol that is only called here,
            and CANNOT be called ever again
        */
        _mint(owner(), 1000000000 * (10**18));
    }

    receive() external payable {

    }

    function updateDividendTracker(address newAddress) public onlyOwner {
        require(newAddress != address(dividendTracker), "RHT: The dividend tracker already has that address");

        RHTDividendTracker newDividendTracker = RHTDividendTracker(payable(newAddress));

        require(newDividendTracker.owner() == address(this), "RHT: The new dividend tracker must be owned by the RHT token contract");

        newDividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(address(newDividendTracker));
        newDividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(address(this));
        newDividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(owner());
        newDividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(address(uniswapV2Router));

        emit UpdateDividendTracker(newAddress, address(dividendTracker));

        dividendTracker = newDividendTracker;
    }

    function updateUniswapV2Router(address newAddress) public onlyOwner {
        require(newAddress != address(uniswapV2Router), "RHT: The router already has that address");
        emit UpdateUniswapV2Router(newAddress, address(uniswapV2Router));
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(newAddress);
    }

    function excludeFromFees(address account, bool excluded) public onlyOwner {
        require(_isExcludedFromFees[account] != excluded, "RHT: Account is already the value of 'excluded'");
        _isExcludedFromFees[account] = excluded;

        emit ExcludeFromFees(account, excluded);
    }

    function excludeMultipleAccountsFromFees(address[] calldata accounts, bool excluded) public onlyOwner {
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            _isExcludedFromFees[accounts[i]] = excluded;
        }

        emit ExcludeMultipleAccountsFromFees(accounts, excluded);
    }

    function addFixedSaleEarlyParticipants(address[] calldata accounts) external onlyOwner {
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            fixedSaleEarlyParticipants[accounts[i]] = true;
        }

        emit FixedSaleEarlyParticipantsAdded(accounts);
    }

    function setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address pair, bool value) public onlyOwner {
        require(pair != uniswapV2Pair, "RHT: The PancakeSwap pair cannot be removed from automatedMarketMakerPairs");

        _setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(pair, value);
    }

    function _setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address pair, bool value) private {
        require(automatedMarketMakerPairs[pair] != value, "RHT: Automated market maker pair is already set to that value");
        automatedMarketMakerPairs[pair] = value;

        if(value) {
            dividendTracker.excludeFromDividends(pair);
        }

        emit SetAutomatedMarketMakerPair(pair, value);
    }


    function updateLiquidityWallet(address newLiquidityWallet) public onlyOwner {
        require(newLiquidityWallet != liquidityWallet, "RHT: The liquidity wallet is already this address");
        excludeFromFees(newLiquidityWallet, true);
        emit LiquidityWalletUpdated(newLiquidityWallet, liquidityWallet);
        liquidityWallet = newLiquidityWallet;
    }

    function updateGasForProcessing(uint256 newValue) public onlyOwner {
        require(newValue >= 200000 && newValue <= 500000, "RHT: gasForProcessing must be between 200,000 and 500,000");
        require(newValue != gasForProcessing, "RHT: Cannot update gasForProcessing to same value");
        emit GasForProcessingUpdated(newValue, gasForProcessing);
        gasForProcessing = newValue;
    }

    function updateClaimWait(uint256 claimWait) external onlyOwner {
        dividendTracker.updateClaimWait(claimWait);
    }

    function getClaimWait() external view returns(uint256) {
        return dividendTracker.claimWait();
    }

    function getTotalDividendsDistributed() external view returns (uint256) {
        return dividendTracker.totalDividendsDistributed();
    }

    function isExcludedFromFees(address account) public view returns(bool) {
        return _isExcludedFromFees[account];
    }

    function withdrawableDividendOf(address account) public view returns(uint256) {
        return dividendTracker.withdrawableDividendOf(account);
    }

    function dividendTokenBalanceOf(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        return dividendTracker.balanceOf(account);
    }

    function getAccountDividendsInfo(address account)
        external view returns (
            address,
            int256,
            int256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256) {
        return dividendTracker.getAccount(account);
    }

    function getAccountDividendsInfoAtIndex(uint256 index)
        external view returns (
            address,
            int256,
            int256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256) {
        return dividendTracker.getAccountAtIndex(index);
    }

    function processDividendTracker(uint256 gas) external {
        (uint256 iterations, uint256 claims, uint256 lastProcessedIndex) = dividendTracker.process(gas);
        emit ProcessedDividendTracker(iterations, claims, lastProcessedIndex, false, gas, tx.origin);
    }

    function claim() external {
        dividendTracker.processAccount(msg.sender, false);
    }

    function getLastProcessedIndex() external view returns(uint256) {
        return dividendTracker.getLastProcessedIndex();
    }

    function getNumberOfDividendTokenHolders() external view returns(uint256) {
        return dividendTracker.getNumberOfTokenHolders();
    }

    function getTradingIsEnabled() public view returns (bool) {
        return block.timestamp >= tradingEnabledTimestamp;
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        bool tradingIsEnabled = getTradingIsEnabled();

        // only whitelisted addresses can make transfers after the fixed-sale has started
        // and before the public presale is over
        if(!tradingIsEnabled) {
            require(canTransferBeforeTradingIsEnabled[from], "RHT: This account cannot send tokens until trading is enabled");
        }

        if(amount == 0) {
            super._transfer(from, to, 0);
            return;
        }

        bool isFixedSaleBuy = from == bounceFixedSaleWallet && to != owner();

        // the fixed-sale can only send tokens to the owner or early participants of the fixed sale in the first 10 minutes,
        // or 600 transactions, whichever is first.
        if(isFixedSaleBuy) {
            require(block.timestamp >= fixedSaleStartTimestamp, "RHT: The fixed-sale has not started yet.");

            bool openToEveryone = block.timestamp.sub(fixedSaleStartTimestamp) >= fixedSaleEarlyParticipantDuration ||
                                  numberOfFixedSaleBuys >= fixedSaleEarlyParticipantBuysThreshold;

            if(!openToEveryone) {
                require(fixedSaleEarlyParticipants[to], "RHT: The fixed-sale is only available to certain participants at the start");
            }

            if(!fixedSaleBuyers[to]) {
                fixedSaleBuyers[to] = true;
                numberOfFixedSaleBuys = numberOfFixedSaleBuys.add(1);
            }

            emit FixedSaleBuy(to, amount, fixedSaleEarlyParticipants[to], numberOfFixedSaleBuys);
        }

        if( 
            !swapping &&
            tradingIsEnabled &&
            automatedMarketMakerPairs[to] && // sells only by detecting transfer to automated market maker pair
            from != address(uniswapV2Router) && //router -> pair is removing liquidity which shouldn't have max
            !_isExcludedFromFees[to] //no max for those excluded from fees
        ) {
            require(amount <= maxSellTransactionAmount, "Sell transfer amount exceeds the maxSellTransactionAmount.");
        }

        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        
        bool canSwap = contractTokenBalance >= swapTokensAtAmount;

        if(
            tradingIsEnabled && 
            canSwap &&
            !swapping &&
            !automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] &&
            from != liquidityWallet &&
            to != liquidityWallet
        ) {
            swapping = true;

            uint256 swapTokens = contractTokenBalance.mul(liquidityFee).div(totalFees);
            swapAndLiquify(swapTokens);

            uint256 sellTokens = balanceOf(address(this));
            swapAndSendDividends(sellTokens);

            swapping = false;
        }


        bool takeFee = !isFixedSaleBuy && tradingIsEnabled && !swapping;

        // if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
        if(_isExcludedFromFees[from] || _isExcludedFromFees[to]) {
            takeFee = false;
        }

        if(takeFee) {
            uint256 fees = amount.mul(totalFees).div(100);

            // if sell, multiply by 1.2
            if(automatedMarketMakerPairs[to]) {
                fees = fees.mul(sellFeeIncreaseFactor).div(100);
            }

            amount = amount.sub(fees);

            super._transfer(from, address(this), fees);
        }

        super._transfer(from, to, amount);

        try dividendTracker.setBalance(payable(from), balanceOf(from)) {} catch {}
        try dividendTracker.setBalance(payable(to), balanceOf(to)) {} catch {}

        if(!swapping) {
            uint256 gas = gasForProcessing;

            try dividendTracker.process(gas) returns (uint256 iterations, uint256 claims, uint256 lastProcessedIndex) {
                emit ProcessedDividendTracker(iterations, claims, lastProcessedIndex, true, gas, tx.origin);
            } 
            catch {

            }
        }
    }

    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 tokens) private {
        // split the contract balance into halves
        uint256 half = tokens.div(2);
        uint256 otherHalf = tokens.sub(half);

        // capture the contract's current ETH balance.
        // this is so that we can capture exactly the amount of ETH that the
        // swap creates, and not make the liquidity event include any ETH that
        // has been manually sent to the contract
        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

        // swap tokens for ETH
        swapTokensForEth(half); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered

        // how much ETH did we just swap into?
        uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

        // add liquidity to uniswap
        addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
        
        emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {

        
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // make the swap
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
        
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        
        // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // add the liquidity
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            liquidityWallet,
            block.timestamp
        );
        
    }

    function swapAndSendDividends(uint256 tokens) private {
        swapTokensForEth(tokens);
        uint256 dividends = address(this).balance;
        (bool success,) = address(dividendTracker).call{value: dividends}("");

        if(success) {
            emit SendDividends(tokens, dividends);
        }
    }
}
```

```
contract RHTDividendTracker is DividendPayingToken, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeMathInt for int256;
    using IterableMapping for IterableMapping.Map;

    IterableMapping.Map private tokenHoldersMap;
    uint256 public lastProcessedIndex;

    mapping (address => bool) public excludedFromDividends;

    mapping (address => uint256) public lastClaimTimes;

    uint256 public claimWait;
    uint256 public immutable minimumTokenBalanceForDividends;

    event ExcludeFromDividends(address indexed account);
    event ClaimWaitUpdated(uint256 indexed newValue, uint256 indexed oldValue);

    event Claim(address indexed account, uint256 amount, bool indexed automatic);

    constructor() public DividendPayingToken("RHT_Dividend_Tracker", "RHT_Dividend_Tracker") {
        claimWait = 3600;
        minimumTokenBalanceForDividends = 10000 * (10**18); //must hold 10000+ tokens
    }

    function _transfer(address, address, uint256) internal override {
        require(false, "RHT_Dividend_Tracker: No transfers allowed");
    }

    function withdrawDividend() public override {
        require(false, "RHT_Dividend_Tracker: withdrawDividend disabled. Use the 'claim' function on the main RHT contract.");
    }

    function excludeFromDividends(address account) external onlyOwner {
        require(!excludedFromDividends[account]);
        excludedFromDividends[account] = true;

        _setBalance(account, 0);
        tokenHoldersMap.remove(account);

        emit ExcludeFromDividends(account);
    }

    function updateClaimWait(uint256 newClaimWait) external onlyOwner {
        require(newClaimWait >= 3600 && newClaimWait <= 86400, "RHT_Dividend_Tracker: claimWait must be updated to between 1 and 24 hours");
        require(newClaimWait != claimWait, "RHT_Dividend_Tracker: Cannot update claimWait to same value");
        emit ClaimWaitUpdated(newClaimWait, claimWait);
        claimWait = newClaimWait;
    }

    function getLastProcessedIndex() external view returns(uint256) {
        return lastProcessedIndex;
    }

    function getNumberOfTokenHolders() external view returns(uint256) {
        return tokenHoldersMap.keys.length;
    }



    function getAccount(address _account)
        public view returns (
            address account,
            int256 index,
            int256 iterationsUntilProcessed,
            uint256 withdrawableDividends,
            uint256 totalDividends,
            uint256 lastClaimTime,
            uint256 nextClaimTime,
            uint256 secondsUntilAutoClaimAvailable) {
        account = _account;

        index = tokenHoldersMap.getIndexOfKey(account);

        iterationsUntilProcessed = -1;

        if(index >= 0) {
            if(uint256(index) > lastProcessedIndex) {
                iterationsUntilProcessed = index.sub(int256(lastProcessedIndex));
            }
            else {
                uint256 processesUntilEndOfArray = tokenHoldersMap.keys.length > lastProcessedIndex ?
                                                        tokenHoldersMap.keys.length.sub(lastProcessedIndex) :
                                                        0;


                iterationsUntilProcessed = index.add(int256(processesUntilEndOfArray));
            }
        }


        withdrawableDividends = withdrawableDividendOf(account);
        totalDividends = accumulativeDividendOf(account);

        lastClaimTime = lastClaimTimes[account];

        nextClaimTime = lastClaimTime > 0 ?
                                    lastClaimTime.add(claimWait) :
                                    0;

        secondsUntilAutoClaimAvailable = nextClaimTime > block.timestamp ?
                                                    nextClaimTime.sub(block.timestamp) :
                                                    0;
    }

    function getAccountAtIndex(uint256 index)
        public view returns (
            address,
            int256,
            int256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256) {
        if(index >= tokenHoldersMap.size()) {
            return (0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        address account = tokenHoldersMap.getKeyAtIndex(index);

        return getAccount(account);
    }

    function canAutoClaim(uint256 lastClaimTime) private view returns (bool) {
        if(lastClaimTime > block.timestamp)  {
            return false;
        }

        return block.timestamp.sub(lastClaimTime) >= claimWait;
    }

    function setBalance(address payable account, uint256 newBalance) external onlyOwner {
        if(excludedFromDividends[account]) {
            return;
        }

        if(newBalance >= minimumTokenBalanceForDividends) {
            _setBalance(account, newBalance);
            tokenHoldersMap.set(account, newBalance);
        }
        else {
            _setBalance(account, 0);
            tokenHoldersMap.remove(account);
        }

        processAccount(account, true);
    }

    function process(uint256 gas) public returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 numberOfTokenHolders = tokenHoldersMap.keys.length;

        if(numberOfTokenHolders == 0) {
            return (0, 0, lastProcessedIndex);
        }

        uint256 _lastProcessedIndex = lastProcessedIndex;

        uint256 gasUsed = 0;

        uint256 gasLeft = gasleft();

        uint256 iterations = 0;
        uint256 claims = 0;

        while(gasUsed < gas && iterations < numberOfTokenHolders) {
            _lastProcessedIndex++;

            if(_lastProcessedIndex >= tokenHoldersMap.keys.length) {
                _lastProcessedIndex = 0;
            }

            address account = tokenHoldersMap.keys[_lastProcessedIndex];

            if(canAutoClaim(lastClaimTimes[account])) {
                if(processAccount(payable(account), true)) {
                    claims++;
                }
            }

            iterations++;

            uint256 newGasLeft = gasleft();

            if(gasLeft > newGasLeft) {
                gasUsed = gasUsed.add(gasLeft.sub(newGasLeft));
            }

            gasLeft = newGasLeft;
        }

        lastProcessedIndex = _lastProcessedIndex;

        return (iterations, claims, lastProcessedIndex);
    }

    function processAccount(address payable account, bool automatic) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        uint256 amount = _withdrawDividendOfUser(account);

        if(amount > 0) {
            lastClaimTimes[account] = block.timestamp;
            emit Claim(account, amount, automatic);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a contract B: https://bscscan.com/address/0xBdD2274262d05E79FC4ecE64E8238c332f3d3fFc#code

Comment: Hi! We'd need at least the source code of Contract A to be able to give an answer. Are you able to edit your question to include that?

Comment: Hello bro. Follow the code of contract A. https://bscscan.com/address/0xf1018C71eeBe32Dd85012Ad413bAB6B940d0d51E

Comment: I'd recommend pasting the contract code in the question, people are more likely to read it here than they are to navigate elsewhere

Comment: @TheRenaissance thx bro, i edited the post with source code of the contracts

Answer (score 2):

If `ContractB` is using OpenZeppelin's Ownable then there's nothing you could do.

To change ownership `ContractA` has to execute `contractB.transferOwnership(newOwner)`.

The code you posted for `ContractA` doesn't make a call to `transferOwnership()` and it doesn't allow an arbitrary use of `CALL` nor `DELEGATECALL` opcodes.

If `ContractA` were upgradable you could deploy a new version of contract A with the call to transferOwnership, but it doesn't seem to be an upgradable contract. You can't change that after it was deployed.

Comment: contract A owns contract B, contract B inherits from ownable, in contract A there is no function to call transferOwnership in B and it is also not upgradable. I tried to make a dapp by passing msg.sender and calling the transferOwnership function in B. but without success

Comment: In this case, the customer lost the amount that was tied up in contract B